# Why is fetch('api.apify.org') not working when I host it online but do working in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, ip

I got this strange error I don't understand
Have been using for a long time and it worked, just yesterday it stopped working

```
module.exports.login = async(req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const ips = req.user.ip;
  const email = req.user.email;
  fetch('https://api.ipify.org')
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then(ip => {
    fetch(`http://ip-api.com/json/${ip}`)
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      const city = data.city
      const country = data.country
      const location = `${city}, ${country}`
      if (ip === ips) {
        req.flash('success', `welcome back ${username}`);
        const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || '/index';
        console.log(req.session.returnTo)
        delete req.session.returnTo;
        res.redirect(redirectUrl);
      } else {
        ...
      };
    })
     .catch(err => {
       req.logout(function(err) {
         if (err) { return next(err); }
         req.flash('error', 'An error occured')
         res.redirect('/login');
       });
     })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    req.logout(function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      req.flash('error', 'An error occured, This may be due to bad network')
      res.redirect('/login');
    });
  })
};
```

The last catch(err with message 'An error occured, This may be due to bad network' is what am getting

But it working in m localhost, but when I upload it online it does not take any action rather it trows error

Please any help with this?

Thanks for any future help

Trying to get user ip with fecth('api.ipify.org') but is giving me error when I put it online but working in my localhost

Comment: What do you get when you log the `err` to the console, one line above `req.flash('error', 'An error occured, This may be due to bad network')`?

Comment: Yes that the error actually got, thanks I found what actually happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer, node-fetch just currently updated their v3.0.3 package

Reasons is that it works only in ESM which you use 'import' instead of require(), And if that does not work you get error except you go back using v2 or less.

Which is not Ok for me so I diverted to use 'axios'

```
npm install axios
```

Example

```
async() {
  await axios.get('api.ipify.org')
  .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
  }.catch(err => console.log(err))
return
};
```

The `response` contains the ip address
But if you still need to use node-fetch use the link ['node-fetch'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Full code below

```
module.exports.login = async(req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const ips = req.user.ip;
  const email = req.user.email;
  await axios.get('https://api.ipify.org')
  .then(async(response) => {
    const ip = response.data
    await axios.get(`http://ip-api.com/json/${ip}`)
    .then(response => {
      const data = response.data
      console.log(data)
      const city = data.city
      const country = data.country
      const location = `${city}, ${country}`
      if (ip === ips) {
        req.flash('success', `welcome back ${username}`);
        const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || '/index';
        console.log(req.session.returnTo)
        delete req.session.returnTo;
        res.redirect(redirectUrl);
      } else {
        ...
      };
    })
     .catch(err => {
       req.logout(function(err) {
         if (err) { return next(err); }
         req.flash('error', 'An error occured')
         res.redirect('/login');
       });
     })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    req.logout(function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      req.flash('error', 'An error occured, This may be due to bad network')
      res.redirect('/login');
    });
  })
};
```